# Show that $G$ contains elements $a,b$ s.t. $a^2=b^3=e$ and $ aba=b^2=b^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given that $|G|=6$ and is not commutative.

I've showed that generators of $G$ have periods either $2$ or $3$, since $|H_a|=\text{period of generator a}$ divides $|G|$. Since $G$ is not commutative it contains $a,b$, s.t. $ab\neq  ba$. Also $ab\neq a\neq ba$ and $ab\neq b\neq ba$, because it implies that $a=e$ or $b=e$. So I have already found $5$ elements from $6$. $G=\{e,a,b,ab,ba,?\}$. I had an idea to check periods of elements(to suppose $a^2=b^2=e$ or $a^3=b^3=e$), but it haven't helped me.

Also I'd like to have some advises toward solving problems of theory of groups. I'm new here, I feel lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no elements of order $6$ since your group is not cyclic.
Then, any non-trivial element has order $2$ or $3$.
It is easy to show that it is not possible that all the elements have order two or all the elements have order $3$ (show it).
Then you have elements $a,b$ such that
$$a^2=b^3=e.$$
Now since your group is non-commutative
$$aba=b^2.$$
And this complete the proof.

Comment: Suppose all elements have order two, then $abab=e\implies  (ba)(abab)=ba\implies ab=ba$. I have no idea how to show the same for order three. Also I didn't get why non-commutativity of group implies $aba=b^2$ or $abab=e$ for $a^2=b^3=e$ ?

Comment: @Mihail , easiest way to do it is by Cauchy theorem saying that if $p$ is a prime dividor of $|G|$ then $G$ admits an element of order $p$. If you don't know this just try to arrange $5$ elements of order $3$ in subgroups and get a contradiction.